# Add badge to Woocommerce product image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding a "NEW" badge to Wooommerce products with this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_badge_shop_page', 3 );
      
function new_badge_shop_page() {
global $product;
$newness_days = 270;
$created = strtotime( $product->get_date_created() );
if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created ) {
  echo '<span class="itsnew">' . esc_html__( 'N E W', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
}
}
```

My questions are: how can I also add it to the single product page- of course I could use the same function and different hook, but is there a way to combine it? And second, how can I add the badge but NOT if the product belongs to a specific category? I tried adding

```
   if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created AND !has_term ('sale') )  {
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this to show a new badge on the products block and a single product page from the same function:

```php
function new_badge_shop_page() {
    global $product;
    
    $newness_days = 270;
    $created      = strtotime( $product->get_date_created() );

    if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created ) {
        echo '<span class="itsnew">' . esc_html__( 'N E W', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_badge_shop_page', 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'new_badge_shop_page', 9 );
```

To check against categories you can use code like this:

```php
if ( has_term( array( 'sale', 'cat-1', 'cat-2' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    return;
}
```

Your final code will be like this:

```php
function new_badge_shop_page() {
    global $product;

    if ( has_term( array( 'sale', 'cat-1', 'cat-2' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $newness_days = 270;
    $created      = strtotime( $product->get_date_created() );

    if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created ) {
        echo '<span class="itsnew">' . esc_html__( 'N E W', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_badge_shop_page', 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'new_badge_shop_page', 9 );
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add something important: if product belongs to category "sale", a badge "sale" should be displayed. For all other products the badge "new" sould be displayed (if they match the time requirement):

Comment: You can check if product is on sale like this if ($product->is_on_sale()) { badge code }